# Localization of Reverse Geocoding in Google Map API v3 in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an application in asp.net , c# and Google Map API-v3. I want to get address of a location whose latitude-longitude is given by user in CHINESE language.I am using  Below given URL.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&language=zh-TW&sensor=false
```

I am getting result but that does not seems correct.

For Ex. :

```
Latitude=25.01482  Longitude=121.42633
```

Result :

```
242å°ç£æ–°åŒ—å¸‚æ–°èŽŠå€æ°‘å®‰è¥¿è·¯229å··7å¼„15è™Ÿ
```

While using the client side reverse geocoding in Google map API V3,  I found the following result :

`242台灣新北市新莊區光明里`

Please tell me what wrong I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: It's obviously an issue with the encoding, impossible to give an answer without more details(how do you print the result). Note: JSON is always encoded in UTF-8. For me the result of the returned JSON is equal to the result of the clientside geocoding: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=25.01482,121.42633&language=zh-TW&sensor=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obviously an issue with the encoding(JSON is always encoded in UTF-8).

For me the result of the returned JSON is equal to the result of the clientside geocoding: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=25.01482,121.42633&language=zh-TW&sensor=false

When your application doesn't use UTF8 you'll need to convert the encoding of the returned string from UTF8 to the charset of your application before you print it.